# previous button not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello guys i have creates this code but it's not working in  which way i want it to work
i have added some colors here and i want them to come in one by one after i click next button,next button is working propely but when i press previous button it's adding +1 then then go -1 hope you understand what i am trying to ask
thank you
it's only javascript,html and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    #box{width: 500px; height: 400px; background: #CCC;}


    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="changecolor()">
    <input type="button" value="PREVIOUS" onclick="prevcolor()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var boxcolor=["pink","blue","orange","magenta"];
        var i=0;

        function changecolor(){
            var div=document.getElementById('box');
            div.style.background=boxcolor[i];
            i++;
            if(i==boxcolor.length){
                i=0;
            }
        }
    function prevcolor(){

            var div=document.getElementById('box');
            div.style.background=boxcolor[i];
            i--;
        if(i==boxcolor.length){

                i--;
            }
    }





    </script>





    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first set the color and only then increment/decrement `i`:

```
        div.style.background=boxcolor[i];
        i--;
```

So when you have this sequence:

- i = 0, color=grey (not set yet)
- click NEXT
- color=pink, i becomes 1
- click NEXT
- color=blue, i becomes 2
- click PREVIOUS
- color=orange, i becomes 1

See how `i` is always set to the **next** color? So no matter what button you click, the next color is already determined by your previous click.

You can easily catch this type of problem by stepping through your code in a debugger.

## Update

Below is a working code snippet that is a bit easier to follow by splitting the increment/decrement from the actual changing of the color.

```js
var boxcolor=["pink","blue","orange","magenta"];
var i=0;
changecolor();

function changecolor(){
  var div=document.getElementById('box');
  div.style.background=boxcolor[i];
}
function nextcolor() {
  i++;
  if(i==boxcolor.length){
    i=0;
  }          
  changecolor();
}
function prevcolor(){
  i--;
  if(i==-1){
    i = boxcolor.length-1;
  }
  changecolor();
}
```

```css
#box{width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #CCC;}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="nextcolor()">
<input type="button" value="PREVIOUS" onclick="prevcolor()">
```

Comment: thanx buddy i got what i want

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be this one:

**Javacsript**:

```
var boxcolor=["pink","blue","orange","magenta"];
var div=document.getElementById('box');
var len = boxcolor.length;
var i=0;

changeColor();

function changeColor(){
    div.style.background=boxcolor[i];
}

function nextcolor(){
    i = (i+1) % len;
    changeColor();
}

function prevcolor(){
    i = (len+(i-1)) % len;
    changeColor();
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="box"></div>
    <input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="nextcolor()">
    <input type="button" value="PREVIOUS" onclick="prevcolor()">
```

**CSS**:

```
#box{
   width: 500px; height: 400px;
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/jebhktwq/) to see a working example. Hope it's useful!